# Fixed menu loses its fixed when off canvas menu is open

Tags: html, css

My css fixed menu is working fine fixed to the top of the container which is set to position relative however when the user clicks on the navigation link, a off canvas navigation is opened which is also set to fixed but it makes the original menu lose its fixed position.

The idea is that you can open the menu at any point down the page and still see the header. Can someone please help!

The basic code of the page is here -

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">        

            <div id="header" class="clearfix">
                <a href="#" class="nav-trigger">Menu</a>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur totam debitis porro repudiandae accusantium consequatur, reprehenderit enim et eos dolor, dignissimos esse! Reiciendis libero sunt, id quibusdam, harum blanditiis provident?</p>
            </div>


        </div> <!-- /#content -->

        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- /#menu -->

    </div> <!-- /#container -->
```

The essential css is here:

```
#header{
position:fixed;
top:0;
right: 0;
z-index:999;
width: 100%;
height:60px;
background: yellow;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-right:40px;
text-align:right;
}

#container{
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
min-width: 320px;
}

#content{
position:relative;
}

.menu-open #content{
transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
}

#menu{
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
height:100%;
width:300px;
z-index:999;
background: $menu-dark-blue;
transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.menu-open #menu{
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ohuafrc9/

Comment: Well, are you saying that you need to see header on top of menu? Then you should increase the z-index of header. Currently both header and menu are having same z-index and same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because positioning is relative to the element that it's inside of. `#container` has `position: relative` and `#header` has `position: fixed`, so the header was fixed to the top of container (and would scroll up with it), rather than to the page, like you'd want.

I moved `#header` out of `#container` in your HTML and added this line in your CSS:

```
.menu-open #header {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
}
```

I removed all of your `position: relative` properties. They're not needed in this case. All elements are set to `position: static` by default. You only need `position: relative` when you're positioning it's children absolutely.

I also changed `translate3d` to just `translate` just in case. Sometimes `translate3d` can mess with stuff when you're positioning things.

[I forked your JSFiddle with some changes here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zvd13czx/)